# TFS workspaces "Error trying to get mapping"

Tags: tfs, msbuild, workspace, bamboo, mappings

Background : I'm using Bamboo for several projects (business requirement) as a build and deployment controller and TFS as a repo.  The TFS plugin creates a workspace for the projects on the build server as part of the build process.  The mappings are valid and correct:

```
Owner: CORP\TFSSERVICE
Workspace Name : Bamboo_BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1_9c48a010_TEST-BAMBOO
Source Folder: $/Project/Monitoring
Local Folder : C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1\builds\sources\Project\Monitoring
```

This works fine for performing GETS and builds.  However, a side-effect (from the TFS plugin, I'm assuming) is the files are timestamped to when they were pulled locally.  I need the time stamps to match what they are in source.

I could do this in pure TFS/MSbuild (non bamboo) environment with the following pre-build steps:

```
workspace = versionCtrlSrvr.GetWorkspace(strSourcePath);
ItemSet itemSet = versionCtrlSrvr.GetItems(strSourcePath, RecursionType.Full);
foreach (Item item in itemSet.Items)
{
   string localPath = workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem(item.ServerItem);
   if (item.ItemType == ItemType.File)
   {
      ProcessFile(item, localPath);
   }
   else if (item.ItemType == ItemType.Folder)
   {
      ProcessDirectory(item, localPath);
   }
}
 private static void ProcessFile(Item itemTFS, string localPath)
 {
    //change FileInfo modify time
 }
 private static void Processdirectory(Item itemTFS, string localPath)
 {
    //change FileInfo modify time
 }
```

However when I run this code on the Bamboo server, GetWorkspace throws the exception:

```
Error trying to get mapping :
There is no working folder mapping for 
C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1\builds\sources\Project\Monitoring
```

Which is not true, and Sidekick can confirm this.

But since the error says no mappings exist, I tried to create another mapping with the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Creating temporary workspace mapping : tempDLworkspace");
workspace = VersionControlServer.CreateWorkspace("tempDLworkspace");
WorkingFolder workfolder = new WorkingFolder(
@"$/Project/Monitoring", 
@"C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1\builds\sources\Project\Monitoring");
workspace.CreateMapping(workfolder);
```

Doing so gets me an exception saying that the mapping DOES in fact exist:

```
Creating temporary workspace mapping : tempDLworkspace
Download completed with errors.   LastError : 
Error downloading file. The working folder 
C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1\builds\sources\Project\Monitoring
is already in use by the workspace 
Bamboo_BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1_9c48a010_TEST-BAMBOO;CORP\TFSSERVICE
on computer TEST-BAMBOO.
```

So in the end, I can't read the mapping because I'm told it doesn't exist, and I can't create a new mapping due to an existing mapping!  I'm not sure why this isn't working.

---

edit - I can get the workspace object by calling an overridden .GetWorkspace() method :

```
workspaceName =@"C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\BLUEM-BLUE-JOB1\builds\sources\Project\Monitoring";
workspace = VersionControlServer.GetWorkspace(workspaceName, @"CORP\TFSSERVICE");
```

This gets me the desired result, but requires me to know the name that Bamboo gives to the workspace.  I would still like to be able to get the workspace definition from the local path alone.  The builds, the timestamper, and the workspace are all owned/run by the same identity TFSSERVICE.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

which version of TFS are you using? in 2012 + you can set this via an option

see answer in this post for details
[timestamp when Getting Latest from TFS and does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230328/timestamp-when-getting-latest-from-tfs-and-does-it-matter)

Comment: We're using 2010.  And, yes, in this case it matters.  Our components are published, indexed, and cached off the timestamp.  Of course this isn't ideal, but reworking the deployment process is an entirely much longer term project.

Answer (score 0):

do you remove the mapping each time you build? If the plug-in is creating a workspace mapping everytime it runs using the same path, you'll get the "workspace already exists" error. If so, add a final task to delete the workspace. This will ensure there is no mapping the next time this job runs.