# How to reconcile TFS shelveset correctly after a successful gated check-in on the build agent?

Tags: tfs

Here is the simplified version of our gated check-in flow for a **successful** check-in:

1. Apply shelveset (build agent)
2. Build (build agent)
3. Revert Shelveset from Workspace (build agent)
4. Check in gated changes (CheckInGatedChanges activity on the controller)
5. Get the Changeset resulted from checking in the gated changes. (build agent)

This flow is very problematic. Indeed, suppose user A commits (submits to the gate) 100 source files affecting all the projects in the solution and then user B commits just 1 source file affecting just one project. How big would be the gated check-in build for the user B on the build agent?

The answer is that user B is going to "suffer" the same build as the user A.

The root cause: we undo the shelveset before checking in the gated changes and then get them again, this time in the form of a changeset. This bumps up the timestamps of the source files, making them newer then the binaries produced a moment ago from the same files.

That is a problem.

How do I solve it?

**EDIT**

Here what happens if I do not revert the shelveset, but get the respective changeset right away:

```
PS D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2> dir 1.txt


    Directory: D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        10/24/2014  10:36 AM         12 1.txt


PS D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2> tf get /version:C105656
D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckInTest2:
Conflict 1.txt - Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit
Automatically resolved conflict: edit: D:\TFS\DFGatedCheckInTest2\1.txt as TakeTheirs
Undoing edit: 1.txt
PS D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2> dir 1.txt


    Directory: D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-ar--        10/24/2014  11:42 AM         12 1.txt


PS D:\tfs\DFGatedCheckInTest2>
```

Notice the timestamp of the file. It was bumped up. We achieved nothing.

Comment: I don't follow, is this using the built in TFS Gated Build process, or your own custom one. I use the default Gated build for changesets 10 times the size of these without any of the issues you describe.

Comment: We use a custom workflow with the default ‘CheckInGatedChanges’ activity.  Also, within this custom workflow, we call build activity ‘Revert Workspace’ where the build reason is ‘CheckInShelveset’

Comment: What's up with the shelvesets? Why shelvesets?

Comment: This is how gated check-in works. Isn't it? Is it working for you without shelvesets? How?

Comment: 1-4 should be part of the standard Gated check in process that was introduced in 2010. In `1` is this the dev A creating a shelveset, or is this dev B consuming Dev A's changeset? In `2` is this a TFS build or a local Build on the dev's machine? sorry I'm trying to get it right in my head, rereading the Q this is your Workflows process? so this is what happens on the server when a developer checks in his code and a gated build definition is triggered?

Comment: The call to Revert Workspace is only needed when the checkin fails. Since the build agent checks in the shelf set after a successful build. The sources on the agent will already be up to date and won't need to be fetched from the Changeset.

Comment: Could you clarify what happens where and who is impacted? My understanding was that you wanted the Build agent not to rebuild everything, but I now believe it's the user who's locally doing a get-latest. To try and replicate, are you using a local or a server workspace for user A and B?

Comment: This is a Gated Check-In process in TFS 2010. If you are unfamiliar with the concept I can elaborate.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept, trust me. Just trying to understand which workspace on which machine (user A, user B, Build Agent) you're having the issue with. I initially thought the Build Agent, but now I'm thinking that your issue is all with one of the users, possibly the one doing the checkin. Your description of the problem is rather cryptic it seems to all of us.

Comment: I think what you're seeing has been fixed in TFS 2012, and I'm not sure if there is a fix available in 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15230530/736079

Comment: The problem is on the Build Agent. I am sorry for the cryptic description - cannot say I know all the proper terms. And the SO link is relevant - my problem is with get bumping up the timestamps on the Build Agent. I also talk about it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541731/why-checking-in-a-gated-shelveset-does-not-effect-the-pending-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `tf get /version:C12345` updates the time stamp is due to that being the default behavior for it in 2010. This was changed in 2012 and made configurable.

In Visual Studio 2012/TFS 2012 a feature was added that controls the file timestamp on get, read from Brian Harry's post from way back then:

> ### Restore file modification time
>
> When TFS gets files on to your local disk, it always sets the file modification time to the date/time that the get operation happened.  There are some work practices where this is problematic.  Some practices use the date stamp on the file for incremental deployment or other kinds of change management.  SourceSafe had 3 options for setting the time stamp on files:
>
> The time the file is gotten (this was the default and works very well in concert with make and other similar build dependency trackers).
>   The modification time that the file had when it was last edited before checkin.
>   The date/time that the file was checked in.
>   TFS 2010 and before only supported option #1.  In TFS 11, we have added support for option #3.  It can be set on a workspace by workspace basis.  We plan to add support for #2 in the future but haven’t gotten there yet.

<sup>[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/09/01/wrapping-up-tfs-11-version-control-improvements.aspx)</sup>

### Back to the source of the issue

As you mention in your other question, you're using `tf checkin /shelfset /force`, which is where your problem lies. As the answer in your other question explains, that checkin goes directly against the server, the workspace on the server is unaffected and as such is left with the pending changes of unshelving that same shelfset.

`tf checkin /force` is also very dangerous in case anther developer had used by-pass gated build to check in changes. TFS will assume you know what you're doing and will overwrite these changes. So:

1. Developer 1 checks in `filaA.txt`
2. Build server starts gated checkin
3. Developer 2 checks in `fileA.txt` and bypasses gated checkin
4. Build server finishes and uses `tf checkin /shelfset /force` and thus overwrites the changes from developer 2

Instead, what the normal TFS workflow does, is check in the local changes on the workspace of the build agent. `tf checkin $/ /recursive` and it deletes the shelfset at the end of the build, in case of a succesful build and checkin.

This tells the build server to check-in the local changes in the workspace, and it will now know that it has the latest version, and won't have to update the time stamp. Next time the build is triggered the build agent will start with a get latest (to ensure that any bypass checkins are also fetched) and it will know these files are already up to date.

So in general your workflow, on the agent, should look like:

1. If workspace does not exist, create workspace and mappings
2. If there are any pending changes, undo them `tf undo $/ /recursive`
3. Perform `tf get /recursive /version:T` (get latest)
4. Unshelve your shelfset to the workspace of the agent
5. Build the code
6. Check in the local pending changes (`tf checkin $/ /recursive`), don't use `/force`
7. If all of that's succesful, delete the shelfset

If anything fails:

1. Undo all pending changes to reconcile the workspace
2. Leave the shelfset in tact
3. Fail the build.

That way the local workspace will better reflect what's going on and you won't have to perform a `tf get /version:c12345` to mess up your dates.

Comment: No, this is not it. The problem is on the Build Agent.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanations. Basically your suggestion is not to use the predefined `CheckInGatedChanges` activity, am I correct?

Comment: Or upgrade to TFS 2012 or better :) (You should do that anyway!) That would remove the issue you're facing, since the standard activity, with the default workspace behavior in TFS 2010 will indeed cause these issues. In the 2012 or newer template it  should be better if configured not to set the date of the files if unchanged.

Comment: Thank you. You have confirmed what I have suspected long ago.